# Using JQuery Show Text On Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a few graphs that when I hover my mouse over them, they will show some text. First I defined the structure of my text:

```
<article class="basic_metrics">
    <h2>Basic Metrics</h2>
    <p id="number_of_loans"></p>
    <p id="total_loan_originated"></p>
</article>
```

With the following css:

```
.basic_metrics{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

As you can see, the display is `none`. Then I have some JQuery to help me with this function:

```
          $(document).ready ( function () {
                $(document).on("mouseenter", "svg", function () {
                    console.log("mouse enter");
                    $(this).css("opacity","0.5");

                    $("#number_of_loans").empty().append("Number of Loans: " +10000);
                    $("#total_loan_origination").empty().append("Total loan originated: " + 1000);
                    $(this).append($(".basic_metrics").css("display","block"));


                }).on('mouseleave', 'svg', function () {
                    console.log("mouse leave");
                    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
                });
          });
```

Then from the inspect menu `article` does get appended properly to the parent class but nothing shows up.

[image]

Take a look around the blue highlight, you will notice the `article` tag with `display: block`. I thought it had to do with the z-index but I also added that in but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The graphs are being generated by the [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) library.

Comment: try changing the position, may be it is on the screen somewhere

Comment: Have you tried using an ID for the `article` instead of a class? Just wondering if it's confused by the possibility of appending a list of class elements rather than just 1 element.

Comment: Just tried changing the position. Still no where to be found. I generated these graphs using `d3.js` btw.

Comment: try using div instead of article......

Comment: It was because I was appending to `svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `svg` from the event handler arguments and your code works.

*Side note:* In your `article`, you have the second paragraph identified as `total_loan_originated`, but in your JavaScript, it's called `total_loan_origination`.

Here's a [working test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wj5a51g/1/) that doesn't append to `svg`.

**Update:** The text box isn't being removed properly.  [This updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wj5a51g/2/) removes it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Does it help that these graphs are being generated by the `d3.js` library?

Comment: That might have something to do with it.  If you take out the `"svg"` reference, it looks like it works.  I'm mocking up a fiddle right now.

Comment: @anderish Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wj5a51g/1/)... If you remove the `svg` arguments from the event handlers, the text shows up as expected.

Comment: Yep you're right, I am not appending to `svg` now and it works. Do you want to write an answer so I can mark it as correct?